# Unable to Strong name an Microsoft.ToolKit.Uwp.UI.Controls assembly with StrongNamer, Any alternative?

Tags: xaml, dll, uwp, .net-assembly, strongname

1. Installed Microsoft.ToolKit.Uwp.UI.Controls from nuget to use MarkDownTextBlock control in my xaml user control. But ended up with error assembly is not strongly named.
2. To avoid it, Installed StrongNamer from nuget but now ended up with error 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies.

Are there any alternatives to avoid errors from step 1 or step 2?

[image]

Comment: What's the `Microsoft.ToolKit.Uwp.UI.Controls` version that you have used?

Comment: I install  `Microsoft.ToolKit.Uwp.UI` version 6.0, Unfortunately, we could not reproduce this issue, please post your xaml code or share us with sample project.

Comment: These are the project details : Target Framwork - .net framework 4.7.2 , The error i get Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. A strongly-named assembly is required. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131044)'. Hence am using version 6.0.0.0

Comment: Do you development UWP app?

Comment: Nopes, I am trying to use it as part of VSIX project inside tool window. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/adding-a-tool-window?view=vs-2019